# Selecting data.frames in a list of data.frames, based on numbers of rows, with R

Tags: r, list

Here are the two first data.frames of my list:

```
lizlist <- list(structure(c(309, 356, 378, 403, 391, 423, 151, 440, 483, 
493, 504, 384, 525, 523, 522, 523, 1801, 2078, 2535, 2650, 2765, 
3247, 3764, 3826, 4490, 4974, 5106, 5279, 5764, 6372, 6879, 6983, 
1792, 2070, 2528, 2644, 2755, 3241, 3758, 3819, 4481, 4966, 5097, 
5273, 5756, 6362, 6869, 6975, 1808, 2085, 2542, 2658, 2772, 3256, 
3770, 3836, 4500, 4981, 5116, 5288, 5776, 6384, 6891, 6995), .Dim = c(16L, 
4L)), structure(c(388, 409, 460, 471, 493, 514, 537, 590, 607, 
609, 630, 629, 641, 634, 1814, 2089, 2546, 2660, 2774, 3255, 
3833, 4497, 4981, 5115, 5775, 6386, 6896, 7001, 1807, 2080, 2538, 
2653, 2766, 3245, 3825, 4489, 4973, 5106, 5765, 6374, 6885, 6991, 
1821, 2096, 2555, 2668, 2781, 3268, 3844, 4507, 4988, 5125, 5784, 
6397, 6909, 7012), .Dim = c(14L, 4L)))
```

I simply need to select data.frame based on nrow==14, and drop the rest. So in this case, result would be a list containing only the second data.frame. I don't get why the following lapply call doesn't work and return only the first row of my data.frame and still list the first (empty) data.frame.

```
lapply(lizlist,function(x) x[which(nrow(x)==14),])
```

Again, thanks a lot for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is

```
lizlist[sapply(lizlist, nrow)==14]
```

Keep in mind this will return a `list` of all data.frames meeting the criteria (which is generally a good thing). You can use `[[` and `which` if you know the list will only contain one such data.frame.

Comment: Great, is it possible to keep the index of the selected list ? In the example above, list index would be 2.

Comment: `sapply` is better than my lapply attempt that required that I unlist the result.

Comment: The index will be accessible via `which(sapply(lizlist, nrow)==14)`. If you really want the indices preserved I suppose you could do `lapply(lizlist, function(x) if (nrow(x)==14) x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (after I got error messages that helped identify why my first attempt was unsuccessful)

```
> lizlist[ unlist( lapply(lizlist, function(x) nrow(x) ) ) == 14]
[[1]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]  388 1814 1807 1821
 [2,]  409 2089 2080 2096
 [3,]  460 2546 2538 2555
 [4,]  471 2660 2653 2668
 [5,]  493 2774 2766 2781
 [6,]  514 3255 3245 3268
 [7,]  537 3833 3825 3844
 [8,]  590 4497 4489 4507
 [9,]  607 4981 4973 4988
[10,]  609 5115 5106 5125
[11,]  630 5775 5765 5784
[12,]  629 6386 6374 6397
[13,]  641 6896 6885 6909
[14,]  634 7001 6991 7012
```

Your attempt was successful in accessing the desired element in `lizlist`, but it then returned the first row because the which() function was returning TRUE in that element and that was converted to a numeric 1.

To answer your request for the index of the dataframe then try:

```
> which( sapply(lizlist,function(x) nrow(x)==14) )
[1] 2
```